# Javascript: using a function as an object and accessing properties

Tags: javascript, oop

This is probably simple, but I'm not getting it. I'm declaring a function to draw a shape on an html canvas like so:

```
function res08(ctx, color){
    this.color = color;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;  
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(649, 143);
    ctx.lineTo(649, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(661, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(664, 154);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(665, 155, 666, 157, 666, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(683, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(683, 144);
    ctx.lineTo(674, 144);
    ctx.lineTo(674, 137);
    ctx.lineTo(678, 137);
    ctx.lineTo(678, 111);
    ctx.lineTo(648, 111);
    ctx.lineTo(648, 143);
    ctx.lineTo(649, 143);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill(); 
}
```

I thought because the function is an object that after it was called I would be able to access the color property like so:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('theCanvas').getContext('2d');    
var blue = '#9ec3de';
res08(ctx, blue);
console.log( res08.color );
```

But that's returning *undefined*. I also tried declaring the function as a variable:

```
var res08 = function(ctx, color){
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's kind-of weird. Wouldn't you be better off returning a new object from the function?

Comment: well there's more than just this one... and the person who wrote the original code doesn't know oop ;)

Comment: Well my point kind-of is that this is not really "object-oriented programming". It's not unheard-of to store properties on a function, but storing results of function calls on the function itself is unusual.  What is it intended to do?

Comment: so there's about 20 of these, and each is one of three different colors. we want to highlight each on mouseover, so I want to have my mouseover function store the original color so that it can be changed back on mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead use it as a class, calling it via a [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword: `new className()`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5TTR/) is a demo of how that would work. With your code, it would be something like this:

```
function res08(ctx, color){
    this.color = color;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;  
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(649, 143);
    ctx.lineTo(649, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(661, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(664, 154);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(665, 155, 666, 157, 666, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(683, 158);
    ctx.lineTo(683, 144);
    ctx.lineTo(674, 144);
    ctx.lineTo(674, 137);
    ctx.lineTo(678, 137);
    ctx.lineTo(678, 111);
    ctx.lineTo(648, 111);
    ctx.lineTo(648, 143);
    ctx.lineTo(649, 143);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill(); 
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('theCanvas').getContext('2d');    
var blue = '#9ec3de';
var res = new res08(ctx, blue);
console.log( res.color );
```

This works, because the `this` keyword now refers to the variable `res`.

Comment: I think [`this` guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (pun intended) might be useful to use as a kind of reference for what the `this` keyword is defined as in different situations. Really getting familiar with it, as with all other coding habits, just means that you just need to use it often enough though :P

Comment: ha! hence why I'm trying to use it here ;)

Comment: @Andy Oh by the way, in this particular situation, you could also add `return color;` to your function, and omit the `new` keyword. Then you can just get the color by just using the variable `res`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the context, not to the calling function. You can either call your function like this:

```
res08.call(res08, ctx, blue);
```

Or change your `this.color = color` line to this:

```
arguments.callee.color = color;
```

Or your `console.log` line to this:

```
console.log( ctx.fillStyle );
```

There are a number of options ;)

Comment: arguments.callee.color = color; works great and does exactly what I need. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Andy you really shouldn't use `arguments.callee` - it's going away in future versions of the language.

Comment: Good to know - I'll try the .call method

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the function within its body by its name:

```
function res08(ctx, color) {
    res08.color = color;
    // ...
}
```

The context (value of `this`) of a `function` is rarely a reference to the function itself:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

foo(); // [object Window]
```

Comment: that's closer to what I originally was thinking, thanks!